# when to call SQLite cleanup functions?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I am working with sqlite database in iOS.I have used CURD operation in my app.For example to insert data into the database i have used below code.

```
   - (BOOL) saveData:(User *)user
{
    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        if([self getUserData:user.email] != nil)
        {
            [self updateUserData:user];
            return YES;
        }
        else
        {
            NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                               @"insert into users(userid,name,email,password,address,age,gender,phone,qualification,role,createddate,apiKey,priorityid,usertype) values (\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\")",user.userid,user.name,user.email,user.password,user.address,user.age,user.gender,user.phone,user.qualification,user.role,user.createddate,user.api_key,user.priority_id,user.user_type];
            NSLog(@"%@",insertSQL);
            const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
            sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, insert_stmt,-1, &statement, NULL);
            if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
            {
                sqlite3_finalize(statement);
               // sqlite3_close(database);
                return YES;
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"%serrr is ",sqlite3_errmsg(database));
            //sqlite3_reset(statement);
            sqlite3_close(database);
            return NO;
        }
        }
    }
    //sqlite3_reset(statement);
    sqlite3_close(database);
    return NO;
}
```

I am getting memory issues in my app due to sqlite database.I am not able to understand what should be order of calling **sqlite3_reset();**,**sqlite3_finalize()**, **sqlite3_close()**.Please tell in reference to my code so that i can resolve all memory issues in my app

**EDIT:**

```
- (BOOL) insertSeMapData:(Client *)client : (NSString *)userid : (NSString *)sendemailto : (NSString *)assignworkordersto
{
    BOOL result=NO;
    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        InspectionMapDetails *inspMap = [self getSEMapData:client :userid];
        if(inspMap != nil)
        {
            [self updateSEMapData:client :userid :inspMap : sendemailto : assignworkordersto];
            result=YES;
        }
        else
        {
            const char *insert_stmt = "insert into map(inspid,inspectorid,clientid,status,createddate,sendemailreportto,assignworkordersto) values (?,?,?,?, datetime(),?,?)";
            if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, insert_stmt,-1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
            {
                NSString *clientinspid=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",client.inspid];
                NSString *clientid=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",client.clientid];
                userid=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",userid];

                sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [clientinspid UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 2, [userid  UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 3, [clientid UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 4, [sendemailto  UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 5, [assignworkordersto  UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

                if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
                {
                    result = YES;
                }

                sqlite3_finalize(statement);
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"Unable to prepare statement: %s",sqlite3_errmsg(database));
            }

            sqlite3_close(database);
        }

    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Unable to open database: %s",sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }

    return result;
}
```

Above function causing memory issue.Here **Sqlite_open** statement is causing a memory leak which i don't understand why?

Comment: My suggestion is instead of using this code. You can use sqliteManager.h file.

Comment: Then you just have to run insert query. Nothing else.

Comment: oh wow !! you see i have developed the whole app using my approach so no way to change it.just need improvement.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are simple guidelines, and to be blunt, your code doesn't follow any of them at all.

For each successful call to `sqlite3_open` you must call `sqlite3_close`.

For each successful call to `sqlite3_prepare_v2` you must call `sqlite3_finalize`. Optionally, in between you may call `sqlite3_reset` zero or more times in cases where you reuse the prepared statement.

You should always check the result of calls to `sqlite3_open` and `sqlite3_prepare_v2`. If they fail, you should use `sqlite3_errmsg` to log what the problem was.

Do not build query strings using `stringWithFormat`. Instead, properly bind values to the query using appropriate calls to the various `sqlite3_bind_xxx` functions.

The code you posted violates all of these. You have plenty of cases where you don't close the database or finalize the prepared statement. And you are incorrectly building your query with `stringWithFormat:`.

Here's your code all fixed up. Note that I'm assuming all the values you are inserting are strings. Adjust accordingly for any non-string values.

```
- (BOOL) saveData:(User *)user
{
    BOOL result = NO;

    if([self getUserData:user.email] != nil)
    {
        [self updateUserData:user];
        result = YES;
    }
    else
    {
        const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

        if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            const char *insert_stmt = "insert into users(userid,name,email,password,address,age,gender,phone,qualification,role,createddate,apiKey,priorityid,usertype) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

            if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, insert_stmt,-1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
                sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, [user.userid UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, [user.name UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 3, [user.email UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 4, [user.password UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 5, [user.address UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 6, [user.age UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 7, [user.gender UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 8, [user.phone UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 9, [user.qualification UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 10, [user.role UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 11, [user.createddate UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 12, [user.api_key UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 13, [user.priority_id UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 14, [user.user_type UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

                if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
                {
                    result = YES;
                }

                sqlite3_finalize(statement);
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"Unable to prepare statement: %s",sqlite3_errmsg(database));
            }

            sqlite3_close(database);
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Unable to open database: %s",sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

**Update based on the new edit:**

Just like your original code, you violate a few of the rules. Your updated code doesn't quite follow the pattern I gave in my answer above.

The main issue now is that you open the database but you only close it under one of two possible code paths. If `inspMap != nil` you never close the database.

You really should refactor the code so you only open the database if `inspMap` is `nil`. I did something similar to your original code in my original answer.

Comment: Thanks but i am calling close statment when i open the connection & also i have used finilize when done with prepare statememt.Can you repost my code with accurated value.I have been struggling lot with it

Comment: In some case but in many cases your code returns without cleaning up properly.

Comment: can you please update my code it would be great.i am not having idea what i done wrong.I have been trying to resolve the issue for 2 days with no hope

Comment: Thank u so much for your code.I have two doubts why you have not used reset statement.I read somewhere we must close the database regardless if was successfully opened or not.

Comment: if don't use bind staement then will it cause any memory issue?

Comment: If the database fails to open, there is nothing to close. And you really should use bind statements. It takes care of properly escaping special characters. Your `stringWithFormat` code will fail if any of the values contain a quote.

Comment: still having issue for memory.I followed your approach.

Comment: You are going to have to a lot more specific about what memory issues you are having. Update your question with clear and specific memory issues as seen from Instruments and include all relevant code. My answer will solve a lot of sqlite issues but there really aren't any memory issues with this specific code.

Comment: I get memory leak when i open the sqlitedatabase connection. On sqlite open database statement i am getting this issue.

Comment: Like I said, you need to update your question with enough details for people to help you.

Comment: Yes i made mistake.why couldn't i see that.In instruments i can see sqlite page cache in keep on increasing

Comment: I'm unclear, did you fix the code and the problem is resolved? Or did you fix that bit of code but there still seems to be some other issue? If this issue is resolved you should close out this question. If you have some other issue, do some debugging and narrow down the problem, Post another question if you get stuck with the new issue.

Comment: I am fixing problem there is still some function which need to checked.I was seeing on instrument that memory leak for that function is gone now but stll i am getting low memory warning & sqlite page cahce is keep on incraesing

Comment: If you haven't already done so, you might consider limiting the heap size used by sqlite:  `sqlite3_soft_heap_limit64(500000);`, for example, applies a "soft" limit of ~500K (subject to various conditions:  see https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/soft_heap_limit64.html for more details).